# Ubuntu 17.10 renew DHCP IP

Tags: networking, server, 17.10, dhcp, netplan

We've just installed an Ubuntu 17.10 server, and during the installation, it was assigned the IP address `192.168.50.84`.

We've now reserved the IP address `192.168.50.107` on the DHCP server.

The `netplan` configuration was a surprise and, in my opinion, `/etc/network/interfaces` made a lot more sense to do.

Every time the server reboots, it sets the IP address to `192.168.50.84`, and it doesn't seem to ask the DHCP for an IP address.

If we execute:

> sudo dhclient -r; sudo dhclient

The server gets the intended IP address (`192.168.50.107`) from the DHCP.

So, what is wrong with `netplan`? Why doesn't it ask for the IP address on boot or a network restart?
On every boot we get this line in the logs: `Mar  6 18:48:08 blues-web-proxy systemd-networkd[723]: eth0: DHCPv4 address 192.168.50.84/24 via 192.168.50.140`

Thanks for the replies.

We didn't do any configuration, the installation process only asked if it needed to use a proxy server or not - replied no.

/etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# For more information, see netplan(5).
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      dhcp4: yes
```

/etc/network/interfaces

```
# /etc/network/interfaces -- configuration file for ifup(8), ifdown(8)
# Generated by debian-installer.


# The loopback interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

/etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       blues-web-proxy.bluescreen.local        blues-web-proxy

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Comment: How did you configure netplan?  Are you able to include your netplan configuration here so we can see what you are working with?

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `cat /etc/netplan/*` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: What DHCP server do you use? How was the reservation configured? Networkd uses DUID by default as an unique identifier for DHCP and this fails on some configurations.

Comment: It is a Windows Domain, we are using Microsoft DHCP server

Comment: Sounds like this is the same as https://askubuntu.com/questions/987673/how-to-get-netplan-on-17-10-server-to-work-with-a-windows-server-dhcp-server then

Comment: @Mathieu, it sounds like the same issue, but is there a solution?

I just tried to include a line like `send dhcp-client-identifier 1:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx;` in the **/etc/dhclient.conf** file, rebooted the server, and **netpain** assigned a new IP 192.168.50.11, that is not the reservasion we have for it.

Executing the command `sudo dhclient -r; sudo dhclient` worked again.

Answer (score -2):

Its possible netplan left some stray settings depending on how you configured it. Check the usual suspects for "static ip" settings such as /etc/network/interfaces, /etc/hostname, and /etc/hosts.

Comment: This would be better as a comment, as it doesn't provide an answer, just debugging information.